# Can't set NODE_ENV=production with npm and webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to access `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside my app, but I only get `process is not defined` when I check it.

`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p"
},
```

`webpack.config.js`:

`const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() : 'development';`

and below :

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
      'URL_DEV': JSON.stringify("specificIP"),
      'URL_PROD': JSON.stringify("OtherIP")
    }
  })
]
```

In the app source:

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development':
    url = process.env.URL_DEV;
    break;
  case 'production':
    url = process.env.URL_PROD;
    break;
  default:
    url = process.env.URL_DEV;
}
```

And it seems that `process` is not defined... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check if this helps https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2537?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I can't make it work. Actually, it seems I just can't get anything from 'process.env' even if I don't try to pass a variable. Even this 'URL_DEV': JSON.stringify("specificIP")' doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if the problem came from my `scripts` key inside `package.json` but it seems the `NODE_ENV` is now correctly set if I use this :

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --colors --bail",
  "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --colors --bail"
}
```

So I actually used [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and... it magically works.
If you're out of options like I was, you can still give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Passing NODE_ENV like below adds a space at the end

```
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p",
```

Trim it before using the value

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()
```